# swagger2 with spring boot describe request parameter as json

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am implementing the swagger2 for api documentation in my Rest services, my typical GET request is as below:

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/v1/user?request={company:abc, limit: 10, startswith: ABC}
```

There are lot of additional attributes inside the request json which varies based on criteria.
Now I want to describe all those fields for understanding of client in swagger-ui. If I use @ApiParam then I cannot describe all the parameters within request json.
If I use @ApiImplicitParam then it won't be a part of request json at the time of executing it from swagger-ui.

I tried with @ApiImplicitParam as below, which didnt work:

```
@ApiImplicitParams({
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "request", value="request", dataType = "com.mycompany.TestRequest")
    })
```

There is one similar issue reported but dont have resolution for it.
https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2183

Please let me know how can I describe all the parameters within request json.